# how a single file can be linked to two different streams at same time?

Tags: c++

```
 ifstream  fin("test.txt");
  ofstream  fout ("test.txt");
```

The above 2 lines, if written  in the same programme, does not produce any error or warning.
But how can we write and read into a same file at same time.
How does this works?

Comment: The input here is strings. there is no way that the compiler know that you are doing something wrong. I am not saying it is.

Comment: Well, the question is a little bit badly written. You are the programmer, so you are responsible for warnings and errors that a program produces. However language often allow you to check state of the objects. What you could do is to check if both streams are actually opened. Funnily enough I couldn't find anything in standard that would define behaviour in such case, or marked it explicitly undefined.

Comment: you can use a stream with std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as comments say, the compiler as such doesn't REALLY know what you are trying to achieve (and there are certainly cases where you'd actually want to something similar to this, for example):

```
// With exceptions for file operations enabled:

try
{
   ifstream fin("test.txt");
   return true;
}
catch(...)
{
   try
   {
     ofstream fout("test.txt"); 
   }
   catch(...)
   {
     cout << "Can't create file";
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Now, that will (in a rather stupid and complicated way) check if the file exists or can be created. Would you like the compiler to complain about that too? The compiler would have to "understand" a lot of logic to follow when which file is used when, and see that both can't be used at the same (and yes, the compiler probably DOES understand that in this case, since we have a return immediately after the `fin` use - make the code a bit more complicated, and it won't).

Now, you can't read/write into the same file with the code:

```
ifstream  fin("test.txt");
ofstream  fout ("test.txt");
```

Depending on the OS (and the flags used in the layer below), you may be able to actually execute both of those lines without error - in Unix, files that are open remain open in the system, even if something else removes the file (which the second line will do), so you can read the "old" file, and write to a new one. That is of course not "read and write the same file at the same time", but reading one file and writing to another. And in most non-Unix filesystems, this will not work, since the OS will use the same directory entry for both calls, and open the existing file, then the second call will either make the file empty or fail (depending on what OS, and such).

The solution, if you really want to read and write the same file is to either:

1. use `ios_base::in|ios_base::out` as flags when you open the file.
2. use a temporary file for the output side, and rename the file when it's "done". Since most types of changes to text-files require that the file is "rewritten" [except for adding things to the end], this is often the preferred method. Then when the changes are done, rename the new file to the old one (with a `remove` of the original one first). This also means you always have at least one complete file (albeit with the wrong name) even if your program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the C++ Standard precludes this - the request is just passed through to the Operating System, which may or may not allow it.

For example, on some OS/filesystems combinations if you go to create a file with the same name as an existing file, the OS hides the existing file's directory entry/entries so other apps can't open it, but existing processes that are using it will be able to continue to do so; when they all close the file will be deleted.  Meanwhile, a new file can be created with the same name, and after that any apps opening the file will see whatever's been flushed to that new file.

On other systems, some kind of "in use" or "locked" error message may be generated, leading to a `fail`/`bad` state in the `std::ofstream`.

You should always test the success of file stream creation, e.g.:

```
if (std::ifstream in("filename.txt"))
    ...use in...
else
    std::cerr << ... or throw std::runtime_error(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason how compiler can understand that you are doing something wrong, it will not remember all filenames you have ever used in your program. Moreover, if the filenames come from user input or simply from a variable, the compiler can never guess that they will be identical:

```
ifstream fin(s1);
ofstream fout (s2); // is s1==s2?
```

In fact, your case (hard-coded file name) is very unusual situation, so I do not think such a warning can be useful in a general case.

And, in addition to this all, this code can sometimes even work correctly.

For example, if `test.txt` is a named pipe, than you can safely open it simultaneously both for reading and writing. You will still have to do some workaround to prevent blocking, a simplest approach will be to open the pipe in different threads. But you can safely imagine an situation where named pipe operations will not block (I do not know whether this is possible in popular OSes by some OS option etc., but anyway you can always imagine such an OS), in such a case the following code should work without any problem:

```
// (for imaginary OS where named pipe operations do not block)
ifstream fin("test.fifo");
ofstream fout("test.fifo");
fout << 42;
int x;
fin >> x; // produces 42
```

So there is no reason for a compiler to warn or give an error. If you want to check in runtime whether the file open was successful, just check it.